# Error sending email in Laravel using google mail

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

The application could send email initially, but now it displays the following errors. Using the same credential from other Laravel Application is not a problem. I tried deleting the vendor folder and installing it again (composer install).

I tried using mailgun, which is working completely fine. Working with gmail.smtp is the goal of the project.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: have you tried changing encryption to tls?

Comment: the same section of code is working properly on another Laravel project. I also tried changing port and encryption.

Comment: You’re using SwiftMailer, not PHPMailer. I’d guess your ISP is blocking outbound SMTP.

Comment: I solved it. 
I changed the code as explained in Laravel Documentation and run the command to clear config:cache after making changes on .env file. Its working now.